# store archived logback files in a completely separate path

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

```
<appender name="MAIN" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/your-app-logs.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_GZ_DIR}/your-app-logs.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- keep 90 days' worth of history capped at 3GB total size -->
        <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

I'm facing issue with logback where if I set the archive path same as the path of the parent it works well for example if I set

```
${LOG_DIR}=/someDirectory and ${LOG_GZ_DIR}=/someDirectory/archive
```

but when I try to set the two paths to completely different locations for example

```
${LOG_DIR}=/someDirectory ,  ${LOG_GZ_DIR}=/otherDirectory/archive
```

then I can that /otherDirectory/archive is created but no archive files created there.
is there a way to make this work the archive has to start as the parent path ?

Comment: Did you check your program has the necessary permissions to write to that directory?

Comment: Yes, the app is running as root, and as I said the archive directories are created but not the log files ( also I tried to use the "/otherDirectory/archive" for both the active and archived log and worked fine. so I am sure its not permission issue)